# How to write unit test case or Mock Retrofit

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit

I am trying to write unit test case for Retrofit which I'm using to make Google Api call to extract details From google token.
Please help mw to mock this class

Tech Stack
Springboot
(JUnit 4)mockito

i want to write test case for this funcion
This is my function

```
public String extractGmail(String googleToken) throws IOException {

    final Call<GmailDTO> call = googleTokenValidatorAPI.authenticateUsingGmail(googleToken);
    final Response<GmailDTO> response = call.execute();

    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getHd().equals("nineleaps.com")) {
        return response.body().getEmail();
    }
    throw new Unauthorized("Token Invalid");
}
```

GmailDTO is used to store response From call.execute()

GmailDTO

public class GmailDTO {

```
private String atHash;
private String sub;
private boolean emailVerified;
private String kid;
private String iss;
private String typ;
private String givenName;
private String locale;
private String picture;
private String aud;
private String azp;
private String name;
private String hd;
private long exp;
private String familyName;
private long iat;
private String alg;
private String email;
private String jti;
```

}

This is my Configuration class for Retrofit

@Configuration
public class GmailLoginConfig {

```
@Bean
public GoogleTokenValidatorAPI googleTokenValidatorAPI() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    return retrofit.create(GoogleTokenValidatorAPI.class);
}
```

}

and GoogleTokenValidatorAPI class is

@Configuration
public interface GoogleTokenValidatorAPI {

```
@POST("oauth2/v3/tokeninfo")
Call<GmailDTO> authenticateUsingGmail(@Query("id_token") String token);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a project with Retrofit right now to verify for sure the answer, however you should:

1. Chose what kind of tests do you want to run: unit test, integration test,etc?
2. Pick the right tool

Say you want to run the unit test, this means you should treat `GoogleTokenValidatorAPI` interface as a regular java interface. Unit tests do not start spring and to not use any kind of HttpConnection, so you don't have to do anything with retrofit in particular:

```
GMailDTO expectedDTO = new GMailDTO(...);
Response<GMailDTO> expectedResponse = Response.success(expectedDTO);
Call<GmailDTO> call = Mockito.mock(Call.class);
Mockito.when(call.execute()).thenReturn(expectedResponse);

GoogleTokenValidatorAPI googleTokenValidatorAPI = Mockito.mock(GoogleTokenValidatorAPI.class);

Mockito.when(googleTokenValidatorAPI.authenticateUsingGmail(googleToken)).thenReturn(call);
....
```

This test will be fast, and will check your code around the call. You can also simulate a non-successful response like this or even throw an exception in case you want to check how does your code behave if the server is not available

You won't be able to check however that the `GmailDTO` returned from the server has indeed the same structure as you would expect (think about the hypothetical situation when google has decided to change the API), It won't also check that the annotation that you've put on retrofit interface are indeed valid (path, expected headers, etc.). For that you need to create a test that once in a while indeed makes a call to google (which means technically run it with spring that will create a retrofit client stub proxy in runtime). Technically it won't be a unit test and in general you might not want to run it for each build (its your decision basically). Such a test however has nothing to do with your own code around the call, that's why I've focused primarily on unit test approach.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The above solution worked very fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally this worked!!,

@Test
    public void extractGmail() throws IOException {

        GmailDTO expectedDTO= new GmailDTO();
        expectedDTO.setHd("domain");
        expectedDTO.setEmail("Email");

        Response<GmailDTO> expectedResponse= Response.success(expectedDTO);
        Call<GmailDTO> call= mock(Call.class);

        when(googleTokenValidatorAPI.authenticateUsingGmail(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(call);
        when(call.execute()).thenReturn(expectedResponse);
        GoogleTokenValidatorAPI googleTokenValidatorAPI= mock(GoogleTokenValidatorAPI.class);

        userAdminServiceImplements.extractGmail(ArgumentMatchers.anyString());
    }
```